# TensorBoard: Charting 'eval loss' for each steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function, tensorflow-estimator

I'm training a CNN using TensorFlow Estimator. On visualizing the same on TensorBoard, I see that training loss value is being tracked for each step. However, the eval loss is being shown just once(i.e just one data point). I would like to see the graph for the loss value at each step.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, model_dir='./model')

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={'images': dev['train_images']}, y = dev['train_labels'],
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True)

t = model.train(input_fn, steps=num_steps)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={'images': dev['test_images']}, y = dev['test_labels'],
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
e = model.evaluate(input_fn, steps=num_steps)
```

Entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/pratikadarsh/devnagiri-character-recognition/blob/master/src/dev.py).

What should I do to see eval loss for all the steps ?

Comment: I think evaluation happens only when there's a new checkpoint. So even if you run for 20 steps, since its using the same checkpoint, you'd only get a single combined eval loss on those 20 batches and since training loss has nothing to do with checkpoints, its evaluated after every step and reported individually. I'm not 100% sure, but might be worth looking at in this angle.

Comment: True, the eval loss has been computed just for the last checkpoint. But my understanding was that since while creating the input function for evaluation, we are allowed to specify the batch size, the evaluation would happen in steps. For example, my testing data is having 2000 samples and my batch size is 100. So I thought evaluation would be performed 20 times rather than just once. I need to further understand how estimators perform train and evaluate functions. Are you aware of any documentation that explains this ?

Comment: As mentioned, your evaluation would be performed 20 times, but only the combined loss (most probably average) will be logged. I don't know of there's a way to log all the losses, instead of just average. But since we're evaluating a specific checkpoint on given data, having a combined loss over the entire data as a measure would make more sense to me. And as for the documentation, TensorFlow and Google's documentation are the only ones I found worthy of exploring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [train_and_evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) method of the estimator. You can evaluate your model periodically(after every few seconds, you need put the value in throttle_secs option). Below is example code

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn_train(X_train, y_train), hooks=[logging_hook_1], max_steps=MAX_TRAIN_STEPS)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn_test(X_dev, y_dev), hooks=[logging_hook_1], throttle_secs=EVALUATION_THROTTLE_SECONDS, steps=EVALUATION_STEPS)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(myestimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution is to modify the run_config and pass it to the estimator. It worked.
`run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps = 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.estimator.EvalSpec` where yo need to define starting from when to run evaluation  `start_delay_secs` and minimum delay : `throttle_secs`.

Evaluation only happen when new checkpoint is available. So you need to create 
checkpoint periodically using  `config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps = 100))`